# Magento 1.9.2. - Get only last Tier Price in view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, product-view, tierprice

In my view.phtml i would get only last tier price of my product. For example for a my product i have this prices:
100 ($ 1,20) - 200 ($ 1,10) - 300 ($ 1,00)

I want see in my view.phtml only last tier price -> $ 1,00

I tried with this code: $_product->getTierPrice(1) but show only first tier price in page of product.

How can i do?

Comment: do you want to show tier price at specific location?

Comment: Yes, i would show only lowest tier price instead of standard final price

Answer (score 0):

You can get product tier price using this code.

```
$product_sku = 'Your_Product_Sku';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$product_sku);
var_dump($product->getTierPrice());
```

Comment: Not work man, show me only an array with all prices and quantity

Comment: You need to take the value from array which you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->getTierPrice()` will return an array, in your case it would return

```
[100] => 1.2,
[200] => 1.1,
[300] => 1
```

So just call it and pop the end off the array to get the lowest price? The argument to `getTierPrice` is not an index into the array, it's the qty you want the price for.

Or use `Product->getMinimalPrice()` but I can't remember if that needs the price index to be built or not.

-- 
I meant to add that you can see `getMinimalPrice` being used in `base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`